# Vishwakarma, Hephaistus, and Posthumanism

Tags: vishwakarma

Reading the post-humanism of Latour, Barad, and Pickering, it seemed to me that social "science" is bringing religion back into the theoretical mix. The ascription of agency to technology, it seems to me, is going back to animism, such as Vishwakarma in hindu mythology, and Hephaistus in Greek. I searched for prior discussions/writeups on this topic but could not find any. If someone knows of such an article, can you point me towards it?